# Is there a sample of ExcuteDevToolsMethod in cefsharp?

Tags: cefsharp

I am trying to use ExecuteDevToolsMethod to implement cache disablement.

But I don't know how to use it.

```
object json = "[{'cacheDisabled' : 'true'}]";
Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
{
    DevToolsExtensions.ExecuteDevToolsMethod(browser.GetBrowserHost(), 0, "Network.setCacheDisabled", new CefSharp.Web.JsonString(json.ToString()));
}
```

error code

Unable to parse paramsAsJson with CefParseJSON method

I have no other ideas.

Comment: Use http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_DevToolsExtensions_ExecuteDevToolsMethodAsync_1.htm instead, pass in a simple dictionary of key values.

Comment: I implemented cache disablement using dictionary. thx.

Comment: Great. Please consider posting your own answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 84.4.1.

```
Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
{
    browser.GetBrowserHost().ExecuteDevToolsMethod(0, "Network.setCacheDisabled", new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
                { 
                    "cacheDisabled", true
                } 
    });
    browser.GetBrowserHost().ExecuteDevToolsMethod(0, "Network.clearBrowserCache");
});
```

or

```
Task.Run(async () => 
    await DevToolsExtensions.ExecuteDevToolsMethodAsync(browser.GetBrowser(), 0, "Network.setCacheDisabled", new Dictionary<string, object> 
    { 
        { 
            "cacheDisabled", true
        } 
    })
);
```

I'm not sure, but I hope it helps someone.
This will require a solid test.

Comment: Version 85 will include a generated `DevTools` protocol API to simplify calling methods. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3165